# Synchronize two branches that have 7 months differences in one - GIT

Tags: git, github

I have a project on GIT where I have two branches: master and stage.
On master branch is a test version of the shop (the Last commit is 2 months ago) and on stage branch is a live version of the shop (the last commit is 7 months ago).
Both shops have different url's, one is for testing and one live version for production.

Now I need to synchronize both branches and to start working organized which means making changes and testing on stage and then push on live.

Is possible to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Sure, merge one branch into the other.

Comment: But there is a lot of differences between live and stage versions of the shop.  Because versions were not syncing in the past.On master branch is a test version of the shop (the Last commit is 2 months ago) and on stage branch is a live version of the shop (the last commit is 7 months ago).

Comment: There is no avoiding this, the differences are there and will need to be resolved somehow.

Comment: Also, both branches pointing to different URL...

Comment: Which language/framework are you using? Knowing that, will make easier to know how to keep separate configurations for testing and staging environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its definitely possible. So one scheme of things could be like this:

1. Create a new branch from 'stage' and call it 'prod'.
2. Now merge 'master' into 'stage'. After this, 'stage' can be used for as your testing branch for staging changes.
3. Lastly, overwrite 'master' with 'prod' branch created in step 1.

After this, your 'master' will refer to your production branch and your 'stage' can be used for development changes.

**Note:** If you have some changes in 'master' that you want to merge in 'stage' then please merge 'master' into 'stage' prior to step 1.

Comment: I cannot merge 'master' into 'stage' in step 2 because on 'master' is test.com shop and is not working properly as shop production.com which is in 'stage' branch.

Comment: @Dextranovich your production.com site is running from 'stage' branch, which will be remain intact in the form of 'prod' branch from step 1. So after creation of 'prod' it will be safe to merge 'master' into 'stage' so that 'stage' contains development changes, which might not be working properly. Does that work?

Comment: Maybe is better to merge from 'stage' to 'master', because production.com is stable version than test.com...

Comment: @Dextranovich the whole idea is keep 'master' in sync with production.com and all the development changes should be in 'stage'. Technically you can merge 'stage' to 'master' but that will cause 'master' to contain broken/experimental changes, which is a kind of anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I created a new branch called like shop and there I pushed from the current production shop. 
After that, I created new test shop, and pull from the new already created live branch.

So right now, I am working synchronously on both of the websites.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just [merging](https://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/git-3.shtml) or rebasing should work.

The problem is not the time that passed between both branches, nor the amount of commits, but the files that were modified on both sides.

Probably, there will be some conflicts that will need to be [resolved](https://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts)).

Additionally you should handle separate configuration sets for each environment (could be a file for each environment).